# Gmail stuck in redirection loop in Chrome

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

I can't access Gmail through Chrome as it displays an error message saying that too many redirections were triggered. This probably has something to do with the system time as I have to reset it on startup (battery on motherboard may be dead).

I've gotten rid of cookies but this doesn't help. It appears I'm logged in since it was possible to connect to SuperUser.com and I can connect up to Gmail using Firefox.

What solutions can you suggest?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delete both Cookies and Cache, verify your system time is set properly, if it is not sync it with a program like Atomic Clock Sync.  The issue appears to deal with SSL, which if your time is not set properly the SSL certificates will be invalid.

http://www.worldtimeserver.com/atomic-clock/

References:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Apps/thread?tid=1f9a8c45f7e096f5&hl=en

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9958

Comment: In what way does this answer the question? The first thread only has 16 replies of which *one* is a possible solution (which could not be reproduced). The second one is a bug report that is *not* solved, therefore there is no solution here as well (except for maybe clearing cookies, but the OP already did that).

Comment: I have edited my answer @slhck, thank you for the feed back.

Comment: @Sean: You're probably on the right track. I forgot to mention that GMail was set to use https. Also, one of the links in the topics you posted hinted at this. Anyway, this is what I did: changed the system clock (it was off by a month and a couple of days), closed Chrome, relaunched, went in Settings>Tools and then erased all navigation data. That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Great! Now replace that CMOS battery =)

Comment: @Sean Perfect, +1 from me!

Comment: I ended up replacing the computer :p